# Detecting events/retrieving data from existing commercial applications

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, automation

I am attempting to do an unofficial integration with some already existing commercial Windows software. The goal is to detect when a certain textbox and/or label is visible on the screen via our service running on the machine, and then grab the text from said box/label and do something with it in the service. There is no external API we can leverage here.

My research has led me to see about intercepting Windows messages, but I have read a lot of conflicting information about how to go about this (I have never tried this before).

Is there a good way to accomplish my goal? Third party tools are acceptable, but the license must allow distribution to client sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account that you just need to grab text from some control, you can use [System.Windows.Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation(v=vs.110).aspx) classes.

You will have to [find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.findfirst(v=vs.110).aspx) that textbox's corresponding `AutomationElement` by some property (`AutomationIdProperty` or `ClassNameProperty`).

```
var propCondition = new PropertyCondition(
    AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "uniqueTextBoxId", PropertyConditionFlags.IgnoreCase);

return AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(
    TreeScope.Element | TreeScope.Children, 
    propCondition);
```

`AutomationIdProperty` or `ClassNameProperty` can be determined, for example, with [Inspect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx) utility.

Then you can just get the required [text from AutomationElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850176/c-sharp-system-windows-automation-get-element-text).

**P.S.:** WindowsAutomation is a bit heavyweight, so you should take care to not affect overall system performance with overly frequent polling for that element.

**P.S.1** Sometimes neither `AutomationIdProperty` nor `ClassNameProperty` can be used to find the element. In that case you will have to use more complex conditions or even walk the tree manually.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly the info I was looking for!