# need to take full page snapshot of active chrome window

Tags: .net, wpf, google-chrome

on click of a button in a WPF application, i need to take full page snapshot of active chrome window
I have used the below code. But it gives only the url of the active window.

```
Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
foreach (Process chrome in procsChrome)
{
// the chrome process must have a window
if (chrome.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
continue;
}

// find the automation element
AutomationElement elm = AutomationElement.FromHandle(chrome.MainWindowHandle);
AutomationElement elmUrlBar = elm.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,
new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address and search bar"));

// if it can be found, get the value from the URL bar
if (elmUrlBar != null)
{
AutomationPattern[] patterns = elmUrlBar.GetSupportedPatterns();
if (patterns.Length > 0)
{
ValuePattern val = ValuePattern)elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[0]);

Console.WriteLine("Chrome URL found: " + val.Current.Value);
}
}
}
```

I need to capture the full webpage in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find all _AutomationElement_s by using its *FindAll* method. Anyway, this might help you:

```
        Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
        foreach (Process chrome in procsChrome)
        {
            if (chrome.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero) 
                continue; 

            AutomationElement rootElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(chrome.MainWindowHandle);  
            foreach (AutomationElement v in FindInRawView(rootElement))
            {  
                Console.WriteLine(GetText(v));
            } 
            AutomationElement elmUrlBar = rootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address and search bar")); 
        }
```

in which [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187110/uiautomation-wont-retrieve-children-of-an-element) is used:

```
 public static IEnumerable<AutomationElement> FindInRawView(AutomationElement root)
    {
        TreeWalker rawViewWalker = TreeWalker.RawViewWalker;
        Queue<AutomationElement> queue = new Queue<AutomationElement>();
        queue.Enqueue(root);
        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            var element = queue.Dequeue();
            yield return element;

            var sibling = rawViewWalker.GetNextSibling(element);
            if (sibling != null)
            {
                queue.Enqueue(sibling);
            }

            var child = rawViewWalker.GetFirstChild(element);
            if (child != null)
            {
                queue.Enqueue(child);
            }
        }
    }
```

and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23851560/5615980):

```
   public static string GetText(AutomationElement element)
    {
        object patternObj;
        if (element.TryGetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern, out patternObj))
        {
            var valuePattern = (ValuePattern)patternObj;
            return valuePattern.Current.Value;
        }
        else if (element.TryGetCurrentPattern(TextPattern.Pattern, out patternObj))
        {
            var textPattern = (TextPattern)patternObj;
            return textPattern.DocumentRange.GetText(-1).TrimEnd('\r'); // often there is an extra '\r' hanging off the end.
        }
        else
        {
            return element.Current.Name;
        }
    }
```